# amazon ec2 service(linux) Tomcat cannot use port 80

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

Actually it works if i use port 8080 or some values bigger than 1023(i think this port).
but it cannot work if i use 80 port, i start the service successfully, but there is no 80/http listening. I know it should be some privileges issues. but i did not know how to do it.
and actually it is not security group issue in ec2, because i can setup the apache, which is by fault 80 port, and be able to visit the apache website through 80 port.
someone told me only root is able to start the service through port under 1023, so it may be the problem.

not duplicate, ok? they have different issue with me. i setup the security group in ec2, it should be privilege issue for me like how to run the service by root. and that guy is in windows.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be create ROOT, and put some file in it. i think that is issue, why your website cannot visit. i am meet your issue before, that is solution.