# Nodejs App at 0.0.0.0:80 not public

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vps

I am using a ec2 server running ubuntu and nodejs. I thought this would create a valid server that would respond if I went to my ec2 web address.

```
var http = require("http");
var port = 80; 
var serverUrl = "0.0.0.0";
console.log("Starting web server at " + serverUrl + ":" + port); http.createServer(      
function(req, res) {
  timestamp = new Date();
  console.log("Request for URL " + req.url + " received at " + timestamp);
  if (req.url === '/error') {
    console.log('Throwing an error');
    throw "Oops";
  }
  res.end("Hello World " + timestamp);
}).listen(port, serverUrl);
```

I have used nodejs and espesially express for a while but never have tried to deploy it myself on a vps, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: [Did you open port 80 for incoming traffic in the security group administration?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454688/477878) (or whatever it's called nowadays :)

Comment: Is it just me or are all the node.js questions today actually system administration questions? There's serverfault for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have port 80 open on the EC2 Security Group.

Test that it's answering on port 80 by by using `curl` from the machine's command line.

```
curl -v http://localhost/
```

If it's answering via a local curl, you probably just have a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same issue. But tests prove it to be fine - 'connected [...] Accept: */*', though the app seems to hang on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```bash
curl 192.168.1.?
```

check the inet address with *ifconfig* for example.