# how to create multiple ports for apache on amazon EC2?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have Ubuntu 32 bit AMI(amazon machine image) on amazon cloud.

I have installed the LAMP stack on it.

```
apache:  2.4.7
mysql: 5.5.38
php: 5.5.9
```

Above are specification for A-M-P

Then I got the one public IP address.(x.x.x.x)

Now I need to create the multiple ports.

LIKE 
x.x.x.x:81
x.x.x.x:82

is it possible??

I have done some steps for the ports configuration as follows:

1. vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf ==> add line **Listen 81**
2. in virtual host file

> ```
>   <VirtualHost *:81>
>             -------
>   </VirtualHost>
> ```

3. vim /etc/apache2/hosts  ==> added line **127.0.0.1  vhost_name**
4. sudo a2ensite vhost_file_name.conf
5. sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: Yes, Look at the apache [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html) directive. You will also have to open the ports on any software firewall that you have installed and on the ec2 security group.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have added steps I have taken for ports configuration. I got your point about the firewall. But can you please add steps to do it. I am new for the amazon server configurations.

Comment: Steps to add rules to security groups of an instance http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these instructions:

## EC2 Instance

**Update Apache**

**File: /etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
Listen 80 
Listen 81
```

`Listen xx` where xx is a valid port number

**Add/Update Virtual Host**

- Create a virtual host that listens to 81 or the port number that Apache is listening to.
- Enable the site with `sudo a2ensite name of the conf without .conf`
- Restart the apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

## Amazon Console

- Find the security group of the instance on the instances list.
- Go to Security Group (find it on the LHS meun) and add the rules to allow the external world to talk to the port numbers your apache is listening to. Please follow [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule) to add the rules.

Comment: thanks, for those who looking for this answer, here's a related guide on how to allow external world to talk to the port with security group setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group?answertab=votes#tab-top