# how to run a jar in amazon Ec2 and access it over the internet

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am fairly new to AWS Instances. I am able to install java in the EC2 instance and able to run my jar. but I am not able to access the jar from the internet. It's a rest service build using spring boot. It run's in tomcat port 8080. But I see the jar running in private mode where it can only be accessed from EC2 instance(from my understanding). But how can I run the jar in the EC2 instance where I can access it over the internet.

Comment: Assure that the port 80 is open and other permissions on AWS allow for accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add TCP port 8080 as inbound rule to your [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html).

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
  --group-id $SECURITY_GROUP_ID \
  --protocol tcp --port 8080 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
```

See also: [EC2: How to add port 8080 in security group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301)