# How do I get rabbitmq ip address on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amqp

Im confused on how to get rabbitmq ip address on EC2 instance. when I try to run

```
sudo rabbitmq-server
```

It shows this error

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "ip-123-213-44-444"
```

So I assumed that in order to access rabbitmq server it would be

```
http://123.213.44.444:5672
```

But I didn't get this web page as oppose on running on localhost

[image]

I even run `rabbitmqctl status` on EC2 ubuntu instance and it shows this

```
{listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"},{http,15672,"::"}]},
```

on localhost it would show

```
{listeners,
     [{clustering,25672,"::"},
      {amqp,5672,"127.0.0.1"},
      {stomp,61613,"::"},
      {http,15672,"::"},
      {mqtt,1883,"::"}]},
```

How would I get the ip address of rabbitmq server on EC2 instance, so that I could start using it?

Comment: you have mentioned the http://123.213.44.444:5672 but it should be http://123.213.44.444:15672. Did you open the port 15672 in your security group?

Comment: Yeah it is supposed to be `15672` but it still doesnt work any help?

Comment: did you open the port 15672 in your security group?

Comment: Im a newbie and I have no idea what is security group.

Comment: I really need help. If you could guide me, it would be really helpful

Comment: please check this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group

Comment: Thanks I will read this.

Comment: Today I found a tutorial on medium that solved my issue : https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/setting-up-rabbitmq-over-ec2-instances-f4dfe49f6253 .I hope it solves yours too.