# spring boot 2 on VPS can't be accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ubuntu-14.04, undertow

I have an App that made using Spring Boot 2.
I use Undertow as my embedded web server.

My VPS OS is Ubuntu 14.04 lts, and Java 8 has already installed off course along side with Maven.
After my App.jar has successfully generated by `mvn clean install` then i move fat jar to my VPS.

when i run `java -jar App.jar` it perfectly works.
but when i access using IP there is nothing to show from browser.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [EC2: How to add port 8080 in security group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group)

Comment: You are starting the app on 8530 port and as @cviniciusm suggested make sure 8530 port is in security group and browse by including port in Url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved already, it was just missing some configuration on server side :)