# how to expose and hit API service endpoint on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a trivial service that's running on `localhost:8080` on an ec2 instance and was wondering how I would go about hitting a `/views` endpoint for that service.  I wasn't able to find much in the way of documentation around this except for this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html , which seems to suggest that I would be able to hit the endpoint by issuing a get request to `ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:8080/views`. At this point, I would like to make it a public API without the need for a key for simplification.

Comment: The URL would be `IP-ADDRESS:8080/view` (eg `1.2.3.4:8080/view`), or you can use the DNS name that is associated with that IP address (eg `ec2-1-2-3-4.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/view`). Of course, it is best to map a DNS Name to the IP address (eg `company.com:8080/view`) in case the IP address needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure your EC2 instanced has a public IP address and that the security group allows traffic from port 8080. What you really *should* do it put it behind a load balancer.

Comment: thanks. it does have a public ip address and I believe dns, which is what I'm using to ssh into my instance.  The security group by default seems to allow for everything https://imgur.com/jYBYt8K , but I'm still having issues with hitting the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be two security groups seemingly associated with this one instance as shown here:

[image]

I was adding new incoming rules for `default VPC security group` only assuming that the `launch-wizard-1` security group only applied to the ec2's relationship with the launch wizard.  Apparently, it was`launch-wizard-1` that needed its rules changed and so I added a custom TCP incoming rule with it `Anywhere` as the source value.  The only port that was open before this was 22 for ssh-ing into the instance.

I wasn't able to find any threads regarding opening aws ec2 until I strangely got way more specific about the port I wanted to open: 8080, which yielded this thread: [EC2: How to add port 8080 in security group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group)