# Deploy nodejs express on AWS windows server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, iis

I deplyoed my nodejs application on a AWS server with windows server as OS. The application is a simple express server running on https port 443. The application is accessible through localhost, but I can access the app through public IP.

Here are a few things I tried:

- IIS with urlrewrite like so (https://dev.to/massivebrains/deploying-node-express-app-on-a-windows-server-2l5c)
- iisnode

I am still not able to access my app. I setup up inbound rules in my firewall for the port and nodejs itself.

Comment: Can you access it with someone else on the local network, with, say, your phone on wifi?

Comment: What do you mean"The application is accessible through localhost, but I can access the app through public IP."?  Do you mean the website can't be accessed over public IP address?  Could you post your binding host header? In Azure VM, you also need to create firewall inbound rule in azure portal. So have you tried to create rule in security group for AWS machine?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group. Besides, have you check your netsh IP listen list？

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply in my security group. I had set up the IP addresses I was expecting, but one was missing. It is working now.