# Spring Boot app on AWS EC2 only running on localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run my spring boot application on AWS EC2 Windows Server by pulling it from github and installing using maven and then java -jar command to run it. It's only working on localhost but not accessable using public IPv4. I use port 8085 for application and added custom inbound port 8085 in security group.

Comment: You also need to allow (open) `8085` port in Windows Firewall.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338301/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group thread will help you