# AWS EC2 - not able to trigger spring boot webservice from outside but running fine in local host

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am running a spring boot web app for restful sevices in ec2 windows. It is working fine local host. I am using port 8083. But not able to trigger s3rvices from outside.
I have opened port 8083 in security group as TCP.

Plz help..What could be issue.

Same EC2 has .Net web application running and it is working fine and able to access from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that 8083 port is open for inbound and outbound properties in security groups of ec2 instance.

Refer this to do the same.

[How to open a web server port on EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161345/how-to-open-a-web-server-port-on-ec2-instance)

Comment: It worked when opened the port in Windows server firewall.