# Output in browser using Express Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I install nodejs with express in server (subdirectory in ftp,path is /var/www/html/admin)
and in admin folder i created file "app.js" which is working in xshell fine and showing message in console

here is my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

but now i want to show result in browser,how can i do this
i tried with following urls but not working for me

```
http://myurl.com/admin:3000
http://myurl.com/3000/admin
```

Comment: try in this:  http://localhost:3000 if running in local machine, if its a server then :
`http://<SERVER_IP>:3000`, or like `http://myurl.com:3000`

Comment: @ i tried with http://myurl.com:3000 but not worked for me

Comment: where are you running? is it any server? or aws EC2? or local machine?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty: i am running in server

Comment: can you add more info? like server IP, is it in aws or azure or something else? and also how you are running, also the output in the console after running?

Comment: This code looks fine. I think the problem is with the network access that you cannot access port 3000. Can we have more information about the server

Comment: @JanithKasun: server is aws

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty: because i am new in nodejs and i have ftp of aws server, in this server(root),there is site working (with nodejs+angular), now i want to create admin panel so i go to folder "var/www/html" and insert test.html(for test the url) then i open browser and write "myurl.com/test.html" , it worked fine so in same directory i install express and now i want to show in browser

Comment: well, in your case you need to login to that server through `ssh` , and there you have to run like this: `node app.js`, and before that you have to install `node.js` into that system. also, you have to open inbound port to `3000`, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161345/how-to-open-a-web-server-port-on-ec2-instance?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @PriyaJaiswal have you configured a inbound rule?

Answer (score 0):

First get ip address of your FTP server.

Then connect `http://<FTP_SERVER_URL:3000` to see 'Hello World' you wrote in the code.

To browse /admin folder you mentioned and if your express app is running on root directory, try `http://<FTP_SERVER_URL:3000/var/www/html/admin`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.write()` method to write something to the `DOM` object( or in layman's language you can call it browser screen).
Try using the following:

`` app.listen(port, () => document.write(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)) ``