# See jekyll application on ec2 via browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, jekyll

I create a page via jekyll on an EC2 istance.

```
sudo jekyll serve -w

Generating...
                    done in 2.949 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/rstudio/try'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

I would like to see the content (on port 4000) via the browser.

I open the port 4000 (port 80 is also opened) via
[How to open a web server port on EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161345/how-to-open-a-web-server-port-on-ec2-instance)

Lets stay the public DNS (IPv4) is ec2-9-999-999-9.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

But i cant access the content at ec2-9-999-999-9.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:4000.

Note: In generell the access via the browser is enabled. I use the RStudio AMI: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/ and the RStudio GUI is accessible via the port 80 at ec2-9-999-999-9.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0
```