# Setting up kafka in aws ec2

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have setup kakfa on ec2 instance. I have assigned elastic ip address to that instance. I am able to start the zoo keeper and kafka and create topics. I am not able to connect to broker from my local machine. When i searched, I understood tgar I need to configure listener and advertised host name in the server properties file. I tried enterung the public elasticip address but its not working.

Where am I going wrong and what values do I need to configure. I want a basic single node sigle broker kafka setup on ec2.

Comment: Did you updated the address rule? You can do so by following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161345/how-to-open-a-web-server-port-on-ec2-instance

Comment: Do you have anything against using Confluent Cloud or MSK? Would be easier to get started rather than manually setting and configuring yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your `advertised.listeners` per https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/