# Connect to Mysql database from remote

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server

Problem:
I have server where is install Laravel app and database. But i want share same database with another server. And i want enable remote access.

What i tried:
I changed config file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf
commented out `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Also changed to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` or `bind-address = *`, not helps
(this is what everywhere i found to do)

ufw is disabled

`netstat -ltn` returns

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

isn't 127.0.0.1:3306  suppose to be 0.0.0.1:3306?

I try connect from another server

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u pf_remote -p
```

i got error

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (111)
```

I think that port is not open, but where else i can open. Do i miss something?

Comment: DId you [grant privileges](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/) ?

Comment: @Jamie_D yes i grant

``` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;```

and 

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Answer (score 1):

Find `mysql.conf` and set

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Then login to MySQL and run below 2 commands

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pf_remote'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

then

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Then also make sure you do not have any firewall blocking connections, check by

```
sudo ufw status
```

If its enabled, then allow remote connections to MySQL port

```
sudo ufw allow 3306 && sudo ufw reload
```

If you are using Amazon Web Services server then allowing connections from within shell won't work, you will have to allow connections from [AWS Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17182531/4094231)

Comment: i tried, and after utf allow 3306 seems like port still is closed

Comment: Did you `sudo ufw reload`? please share output of `sudo ufw status verbose`

Comment: ufw show that port is active

`3306                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere`
`3306 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)`
```

But when i run port scan it still show that port is closed

Comment: Who is server provider? digitalocean? AWS?

Comment: neither - Flaunt7

Answer (score 0):

Try to grant priviliges to user for remote access:

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL ON yourDatabase.* TO user@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourPassword';
```

Also please remember to restart your mysql service after config changes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: You should check to see if your server is running [APF](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/) or some other advanced firewall protection.