# Hosting R Plumber on AWS EC2

Tags: r, plumber

[image: Picture of Rstudio Login]I'm pretty new into the whole app development ecosystem and I currently have R Studio running on an EC2 instance on AWS. I was hoping to use this to deploy an R Plumber API that would be used by my frontend in React. Is there a way to allow universal access to my Plumber API this way? I can run my R code and access the API from my EC2, but if I try to access the API from another computer, I have to sign into the EC2. Apologies if this doesn't quite make sense, but I would be happy to try to answer any question that come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to that

[How to open a web server port on EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161345/how-to-open-a-web-server-port-on-ec2-instance)

Run plumber with host 0.0.0.0 and a port of your choice.

Comment: Got it. I'm still having the issue of having to sign in whenever I want to access the API however. Screenshot provided.

Comment: Run your plumber APi as a service, detached from RStudio. See https://github.com/meztez/plumberDeploy/blob/5c3537f4163032fd46e90a08b75f32e5de2850cb/R/digital-ocean.R#L325 and https://github.com/meztez/plumberDeploy/blob/master/inst/server/plumber.service for inspiration.