# How to debug or fix Connection Refused trying to curl EC2 instance port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection

I've created an EC2 instance, but I seem unable to reach a service I've launched on it (say on port `1234`). The instance is

- part of a permissive security group with all traffic from anywhere allowed (I know this is not advisable, but it's just to get this working)
- in a public subnet of a VPC

I've launched an `httpd` server on the instance and verified I can reach it on port `80` from either my machine or another EC2 instance in the same subnet. I've also verified that I can curl `localhost:1234` from the original EC2 instance.

But I get `Failed to connect to $MY_IP port 1234: Connection refused` whenever I try to curl the port from my machine or the other EC2 instance in the same subnet (trying both private and public IP). What could still be blocking the request? How can I start to debug?

I've already looked through [answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161345/how-to-open-a-web-server-port-on-ec2-instance), but my security group should already allow this traffic.
[image: security group detail]

Comment: Can you clarify? You wrote that it works "I can reach it on port 80", but then it does not work? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to run my own service, not `httpd`. I would prefer to run on some arbitrary port (say `1234`), but even if I try to use port `80` for the service (with `httpd` off), I get a `Permission denied` error from the Linux OS on service startup.

Comment: If you ssh to the instance, can your `curl` your application on your port to confirm that it works?

Comment: Yes, I can `curl localhost:1234` from the instance running the service. I can't curl it from the other EC2 instance I've spun up though

Comment: Maybe you bound your app to localhost, not regular network interface. Also make sure you don't have any os-level firewalls (ufw).

Comment: Aha that was it. I see now that binding to `localhost:1234` filters out traffic from other IPs, and `0.0.0.0:1234` listens to traffic from all IPs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by binding application to `localhost`, which makes it only accessible from within the instance. Changing the binding to `0.0.0.0` **solved** the problem.