# Setting up Nginx on a new micro-instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm trying to figure out how to set up Nginx on a micro-instance on AWS.

The micro-instance is set up and running. I've associated an elastic IP to it. I SSH into it, make a new user run `apt-get upgrade`, then `apt-get install nginx`. Nginx gets installed. Then I run `sudo service nginx start`. It looks like nginx is started. I can see the workers as running processes.

So I try to access the server through the public IP ie. elastic IP via my browser in hope of seeing the 'Welcome to Nginx' screen. But all I get is the message that the server can't be found.

I'm clueless on how to continue.

Comment: Try this `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To verify that the problem isn't with the server, try running a `wget http://localhost/` from your instance and see if you get the page you're expecting.  If you do, it's probably firewall related.

When you created your instance, you had to provide a security key (this is what you use to ssh into it) and a security group.

You need to make sure that your security group has port 80 open (assuming you have nginx configured on port 80).

If you have a new AWS account, and you're running your instance inside a VPC, you need to make sure your VPC has an internet gateway attached.

Comment: Rejoice! That did it. StackOverflow helped also helped me with [Opening port 80](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services)

Comment: Was lost until I found the Opening port 80 hint!! thanks guys

Comment: Adding a TCP inbound rule for port 80 in security group helped!