# AWS: Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I hope you can help.
I'm trying to setup a wordpress blog. In the past I've been using HostGator but now making the switch to AWS. However, I'm having problems with the basics.

I have created an instance and managed to login to the instance via putty. 
In S3 I have created 2 buckets. lmof.uk and www.lmof.uk (following one of the AWS guides) and uploaded a php file to lmof.uk

In Route 53, I have added the Domain to the Hosted Zone, created A record and CNAME as well.
Updating my Nameservers from my register and if you visit lmof.uk it downloads the php file.

When I log into my Putty, I can't seem to find the php file anywhere. I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbQSs-_d-yM but when it came to looking at my public ip address, the connection times out.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but at this stage I'm just looking to install wordpress, see the files, edit them and see the changes on the website.

Comment: What you are trying to do does not normally involve S3 buckets. It sounds like you're following a guide on how to set up a static site on S3, which is a very different thing than installing wordpress on EC2 and hosting a web site there.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'll find a different guide to follow.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to open port 80 on security groups.follow the link below
[Opening port 80 EC2 Amazon web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services)