# Can't access express server on ec2

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm using Express 4 installed on an amazon ec2-server. I was wondering why I can't access my server with the public-ip:8000/

Here is my code for the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});
```

Comment: Dump your firewall config here? What is the IP and port, happy to try to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you aren't setting up the Express and HTTP server correctly; [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) is itself a wrapper for the [HTTP module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html).
This would be a correct setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8000);
```

**Edit**: the issue actually had to do with the firewall of the server (along with the app). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454688/2708970) helped solve the issue.

Comment: Yea, that doesn't work either. If it is a firewall. I guess it is as firewall issue. How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: @ArjunPatel sorry my original answer didn't fix it - maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454688/2708970) will help.

Comment: @ArjunPatel you're welcome - I've edited this answer to include the answer link and explanation. :)