# Login to EC2 server to create MySQL database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had a friend create an AWS account and an EC2 instance after which he gave me the username and password to login. I am having a lot of trouble getting into the server with the information he gave me. I'm new to amazon services so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not. I seem to be able to login using PuTTy, but it doesn't prompt me for a password, I just get through with the username alone. copying the ip into a browser just gets me a "This webpage is not available" 
message. He also gave me the key file but I'm sure where to use it.

Anyone know how I can get into the server to modify the database?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a message 'This webpage is not available' then it could be there is no HTTP server running on port 80, or the security group configured on the EC2 instance is set to deny connections to port 80. If it is a new instance, there probably isn't a firewall configured locally to deny connections.

If you are sure there is a server running on port 80, you can use these instructions to tunnel through SSH

Set up your PuTTY window like this, and hit the Add button

[image: putty]

Navigate to http://127.0.0.1 and you should see the web server if there is one running, if you can navigate using this way, [you have a problem with your security group configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services#answer-10454688). If you cannot, you do not have a HTTP server running to connect to. If there is not one running (and I am assuming you wish to use phpMyAdmin), you may have to set up apache and [install phpMyAdmin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin)

As you connect without a password, do you receive a line along the lines of 
'Authenticating with public key "unipc-rpi"' or mentioning 'Pageant', because it means that instead of a password, PuTTY is [authenticating using a public key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and not a password.