# Port 80 closed on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

i've problem with the port 80 on EC2 instance.

I already added on Security Groups as in this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services/10454688#10454688), but not working.

The site hosted in this instance cannot access from external IP.

Inside RDP Instance, i run the command: "netstat -an" and returned the following result.

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:21             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5985         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:47001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

If i ping the site: yellowlab.com.br it reply

```
 Pinging yellowlab.com.br [54.94.139.119] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 54.94.139.119: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
 Reply from 54.94.139.119: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
 Reply from 54.94.139.119: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
 Reply from 54.94.139.119: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
 Reply from 54.94.139.119: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
```

but when access by browser i got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT.

I`ve checked the port by http://ping.eu/port-chk/ and returning:
**54.94.139.119:80 port is closed**

The elastic IP is: 54.94.139.119

Is there something else I have to do?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**:

As the solution given by @Doon, i edited the config by prompt as bellow:

```
 netsh
 netsh>http
 netsh http>add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: adjust your config to have the webserver listen on `0.0.0.0`. right now the config is listening only on localhost (which is `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: Thank you so much @Doon.

To help others with the problem, i put the solution on description issue: