# Allow external access on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Can I make a binding to have my client access the website I am working on without RDPing into the EC2 instance and accessing via Localhost? in the security group settings for EC2 I have an Inbound rule for HTTP Port 80 IP: 0.0.0.0/0.

But when I call my website from other IP by the EC2 IP/index.aspx it wont work.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening port 80 EC2 Amazon web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services)

Comment: Check if you have a local (Windows?) firewall running on the instance as well and if the web server is bound to the external interface.

Comment: Actually I disabled the firewall on EC2, added Port 80 access 0.0.0.0 on Sec Groups and still its not working, should I use the Public IP or Public DNS of my EC2 instance??

Comment: Have you checked the local Windows firewall and the web server settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had to go the the EC2 Insance Secuirty Group associated to that instance (EC2 Instance > Details > Security Group) I had only enabled the RDP for the EC2 Instance.