# Amazon AWS EC2, Allow inbound http Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a nodejs application in AWS EC2 instance. It has API gateway with '/api/companies' endpoint. After starting my server I am able to cURL from the instance terminal and it returns the result correctly. But I am not able to make the request from my browser to the EC2 instance. I am not sure exactly how to modify the inbound rules to make this work

Comment: What port the server is listening to?

Comment: The app runs on 8080. But It can be customised.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [Security Group Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules) documentation, but the gist is:

1. Create a new Security Group in your VPC for your EC2 instance
2. In the Inbound rules, create a new rule
3. Set the Source to your IP address. (Optional, if you want to allow access from any IP address, enter `0.0.0.0/0` in the Source)
4. Set the Protocol to `tcp`, and set the Port to `80` or `443` depending on what your application uses

Answer (score 4):

- Edit your existing security group or add a new security group
- Select the VPC the instance is running in. The attached image shows `No VPC`, but you have to select your VPC
- For `Source`, you can choose  `My IP` if you want to allow inbound traffic from your IP only or from `Anywhere` in the world

[image]