# URL inaccessible in local machine but accessible in deployed machine

Tags: url, curl, amazon-ec2, apic

I have made an api using api connect, When i deploy API on the AWS instance and access it using CURL, it gives me the html code of the page residing there. But when I access the same url from my local machine (by using the address of deployed machine). Page doesnt opens. Connection times out.

What actually the problem is ??

Comment: check your security group inbound rule to see if it allows inbound traffic from your IP to the port your api is listening to. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271531/amazon-aws-ec2-allow-inbound-http-request

Comment: I have checked the security rules and they are correct. I have also opened the port but still not getting any response on my browser. @ChackoMathew