# How to configure the sites-available file for a specific site in nginx for a Laravel application?

Tags: nginx, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.4, php-7

I'm trying to deploy a **Laravel 5.4** application through **Nginx**. So, I'm more or less following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

My server is an Amazon EC2 running Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0. Nginx version is the 1.10.3.

At the current moment, I do not have a domain to my application, so I can only access it through the ip. I want to access my application through an URL similar to the following:

```
http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/my-site
```

However, trying to do it shows an error 403.

If I try to access directly the public folder (`http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/my-site/public`), I'm receiving the home page of my application, but the links are broken. Since I got a Laravel error when I did a mistake, it seems to be working.

The port 80 is open (by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454688/5696068)), and if I simply create a folder inside `/var/www/html` and put an `index.php` file I can access it through the browser. Trying to access `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` shows the `Welcome to nginx` default page, so nginx is working.

Artisan (`php artisan serve`) it seems to work in the terminal, but when I try to access it through the browser (`http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000`), connection is refused (and I opened the port 8000 too).

Trying to access directly through the ip () results in the same behavior for every URL (`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` shows nginx welcome, `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/my-site` returns a 403 error etc.)

I *think* my problem is with the **sites-available** files. I'm not sure how to properly **name the file for my specific application**, and I feel this is the problem - so nginx is not able to identify the file and so apply the configurations in the site:

Without the comments, here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And this is the content of the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/my-site/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/my-site;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And here is my `nginx.conf` file content:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

P.s.: I already created the symbolic link for the `sites-enabled` folder.

I tried to use the EC2 domain (`ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` in the `server_name` of both files, but it returned an error when I tried to restart nginx.

Removing the `/my-site` part of the my-site file `server_name` still returned a 403 error in the `ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/my-site` URL. However, if I remove the default nginx welcome file (`index.nginx-debian.html`), I am able to access the intended home page by the `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` URL, without the `my-site` in it. Links are working as well; however, JS files both external and inside the same ip are not being loaded due to "Content Security Policy", and the URL is not the one I intended.

So, **is there something wrong about these configurations**, specifically about the server names and the name of the file?

Comment: [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) could not contain '/'.

Comment: I would say that you might set the `server_name` to your `EC2` public domain. Then check if you could access or not.

Comment: @paul, when I used `ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` in server name, nginx returned an error. Removed `/my-site` from the my-site file and it's still returning the same errors; I will edit the question to include these tries

Comment: Could you post the contents of `nginx.conf`?

Comment: @paul, sure added it

Comment: Well, I tried more changes and I was able to at least get a different error... I'll update the question to show that

Comment: You could access `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/my-site/public`. `my-site/public` is called `routing`, and laravel is responsible to deal with it.

Comment: @paul, ok, I'll try to work on it later, since I'm able to at least get the site through `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. Now I'm trying to fix the content security police, which is a separated problem that this one. Thanks!