# How to send an API request with postman to my RESTful API on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an API with flask and I'm trying to use Postman to test it, I think I'm not using the correct request URL.

On postman I am sending a GET request to the public DNS of my EC2 instance `ec2-1-1-111-10.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/`

My flask endpoint looks like this

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8080")
```

Sending a request to `http://localhost:8080/` works fine but when trying to make a request to my app running on EC2 postman just hangs waiting for a response

I am unable to choose a port number other than 80

So I managed to get a response using 0.0.0.0/0 as my source but I would like to allow only requests from a particular IP, my IPv4 does not have a slash in what should I put there 0.0.0.0/???
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that port hasn't been forwarded you can look how to do that
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services)

Comment: I think you are correct but when I choose HTTP as the request type it will only let me use port 80, however setting my application to use port 80 gives a permission denied error when trying to run my Flask app

Comment: You can choose a custom port in the drop down